# Is there possibility to tweak the json output in karate?

Tags: karate

Is there a possibility to tweak the output 1 to output 2

*def dataset = databaseMethods.runJsonQuery(result, query) Then print dataset

output 1 : [{"Account no :"123", "Key" : "9989"}, {"Account no :"345", "Key" : "9889"},{"Account no :"569", "Key" : "9989"}]

expected output what i require :
{
"recordset": [
[{"Account no :"123", "Key" : "9989"}, {"Account no :"345", "Key" : "9889"},{"Account no :"569", "Key" : "9989"}]
}

if possible can you give solution

I am doing POC to adapt the karate framework for integration (api + database) automation in my company.

Comment: I accepted it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

But this specific case is very simple:

```
* def output2 = { "recordset": "#(output1)" }
```

Also note that Karate is almost like JS, so you can even do this.

```
* def output2 = {}
* output2.recordset = output1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Peter for your replies , I am very happy for selecting karate as my intregration automation .it's ease our work . Thanks again for helping out whenever we are stucked